# How can I parse a property and inject values back into the Environment?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a property that I would like to parse and inject values back into the Environment. I would like to make these values available using the @Value annotation.

Eg. properties file or a system property:

```
settings.compoundProperty=abc.xyz.123
```

I would like to parse that and inject

```
prop1=abc
prop2=xyz
prop3=123
```

back into the Environment. I would like to be able to inject these new properties in my bean as follows:

```
@Value("${prop1}") prop1;

@Value("${prop2}") prop2;
```

I tried this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties (prefix="settings")
public class EnvironmentProperties {
      @Inject ConfigurableEnvironment env;

      public void setCompoundProperty(String s) {
           // parse s and inject prop1, prop2 and prop3 back using env
      }
```

However that works only if I include

```
@Inject EnvironmentProperties envProps;
```

in the class with the @Value("${prop1}") prop1;    attributes.

How can I do this without needing to include envProps as mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spring Expression Language (SpEL)

All your properties can be accessed using `Environment` so in the code below you are accessing to prop1 and inject in the `value` String

```
@Value("#{environment.prop1}")
private String value;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I am able to access these properties like this: `@Value("#{environmentProperties.prop1}")
private String value;`